# Python and csv files

Tags: python, csv

So i am working on a python assignment and I am stuck.  the assignment...
"In this project you will write a program that reads a file of bank account data, modifies the data and writes the new data to a new file.  This file, named accounts.csv,  will be a CSV (Comma Separated Values) formatted file that contains the following fields of information:

accountNumber, firstName, lastName, accountBalance

Your program will read from this file, process each line of CSV data into a list, making sure to convert data types properly.  This will result in a list of lists, where each sub list represents one account field.

After the file has been read and the accounts list has been created, your program will then add $10 to the accountBalance for each account, then this new data will be written to a new file called adjustedAccounts.csv"

The accounts.csv contains " 1012,Tony,Stark,8388743.54
1034,Peter,Parker,775.12
1290,Clark,Kent,34.88
1538,Diana,Prince,23744.95
2008,Billy,Batson,90.11
1169,Bruce,Wayne,6100187.33
2217,Bruce,Banner,-34.50
1444,James,Howlett,0.75
1111,Wade,Watts,300.20"

```
def main():
infile = open('accounts.csv', 'r')
outfile = open('adjustedaccounts.csv', 'w')    


for line in infile:
    Customer = line
    
    
   # accountNumber, firstName, lastName, accountBalance
    
    print(Customer, file=outfile)

#for i in range(accountBalance):
    #accountBalance + 10 = newBalance

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

main()

I know i need to get accountBalance as an int but I cant seem to get it assined and getting the rest of the data to display also. Any help is greatly appericated!! Thank You!

Comment: [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: Have a look at at pathlib if you are using python 3. Also look up the `with` statement.

Comment: To get the comma separated data, you can use `line.split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

this one:

```
def main(infile,outfile):
    import csv

    f_in = open(infile,'r')
    f_out = open(outfile,'w')
    
    f_read = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=',')
    f_write = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',')

    for line in f_read:
        # balance is line[3]
        balance = float(line[3])
        balance += 10
        line[3] = str(balance)

        f_write.writerow(line)

    f_in.close()
    f_out.close()

main('accounts.csv','adjustedaccounts.csv')
```